# How do i retrieve a sandwiched/ internal URL parameter in Angular?

Tags: angular, parameters, router

So my url route is 'players/:id/listview'

(listview being a sub-component of the objects component)

My routing module:

```
path: 'players/:id',
    component: PlayersComponent,
    children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'listview' },
        { path: 'listview', component: ListviewComponent }
    ]
```

I tried

```
this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id")
```

output: null

Then I tried

```
this.route.snapshot.param
```

output: {}

How do I get the id from this route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the parent of your current route:

```
this.route.parent.snapshot.paramMap.get("id")
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can get according to below

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class LoanDetailsPage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  id: number;
  private sub: any;

  constructor(private myroute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.myroute.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.id = params['id'];
       this.id = +params['id'];
     // (+) converts string 'id' to a number

    });
  }
```